# Is any way to add latency to a service(or a port) in K8s?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a pod and a service, basically the problem is that I want the traffic to port 11010/TCP to arrive with a delay for testing purpose:

NAME                                         READY       STATUS     RESTARTS   AGE
pod/regression                       1/1     Running     0          6m58s

NAME          TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)
service/regression   ClusterIP   some_ip           **11001/TCP,8080/TCP,8081/TCP,11010/TCP**   6m59s

Is any possible way of doing it with k8s like:

```
    ---
        apiVersion: v1
        kind: Service
        metadata:
          name: regression
        spec:
          ports:
            - name: port-11010
              port: 11010
              targetPort: 11010
              protocol: TCP
>>>>>>>>>>    delay: 10ms    <<<<<<
          selector:
            service: regression
        status:
          loadBalancer: {}
```

Comment: use a proxy for this testing purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no straightaway solution to this..
but you can use service mesh to achieve this..
I am familiar with istio (not sure with any other service mesh solution) and this could give some idea on how to achieve your query
https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/fault-injection/